# binding two buttons to the same widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

Is it possible to bind two diff keys to the same widget and call a different  function. I am getting error that `dbase() missing positional argument event` even though i have passed in event as an argument

**UPDATE**: So the actual error is when i bind 'Return' to an entry widget and then i try clicking the button, then i get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: dbase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

Code:

```
def search():
    log = Toplevel(root)
    log.title('Search Book')
    def dbase(event):
        .....
    def clicker(event):
        ....
    def key_pressed(event):
        ....

    entry1.bind_all('<Key>',key_pressed)    
    button1.bind('<Button-1>',clicker)
    entry1.bind('<Return>',dbase)
```

Comment: It works fine on my PC.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA updated the Q

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley updated yet again

Comment: `def dbase(event=None):`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i think that just solved the error for now, thanks can you explain wt it does and add as an answer

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me when I add print statements in the functions.

Comment: for me it gives that error :( but after @jizhihaoSAMA comment its fine

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for it to give that error: dbase clearly accepts `event` as a parameter and all bound functions are called with that parameter. I think there's something you're neglecting to mention. Are you trying to configure the button to have `command=dbase`? That would cause the error, but you haven't shown that in your examples.

Comment: oh my bad, the button does have `command=dbase` whats the issue there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the button, it will call the function `dbase`.
But your function `dbase` need to pass an argument `event`, but at this time, it won't pass any arguments.That's why it will raise Exception(If you call the `dbase` by the `.bind`, it will pass a argument).To solve this issue, you need to bind a default argument for your `event`:

```
import tkinter

def dbase(event=None):
    print("you are passing")

r = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(r,command=dbase)
r.bind_all("<Return>", dbase)
b.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

Or if you don't need the argument,use `lambda` in the `bind`:

```
import tkinter

def dbase():
    print("you are passing")

r = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(r,command=dbase)
r.bind_all("<Return>", lambda e: dbase())
b.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

This could work when you press the button directly or press `<Enter>`.

Comment: ok so we cant bind in the button? only in the `r` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud: you can add bindings to buttons. Usually you shouldn't, though, since buttons support a `command` option.

Comment: @CoolCloud The only time I can think you need to bind to a button is when you have to bind it to a binding, such as `<Key>` and `<Double-Button>`.

Comment: i know its been over a month, but a quick doubt, what if i want to use some properties related to event, inside by function to be triggered, when i click the button

Comment: @CoolCloud The first solution has passed the argument `event`, you could use it when you use bind to trigger it.

Comment: but it is `None` right? i get error `None has no attribute 'keysys'`

Comment: @CoolCloud Press the button won't pass `event` argument.